# Make links open new window in specified terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, browser

I use [links](http://links.twibright.com/) browser for occasional browsing. Links has an option to open a new window. This can be done by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and going to `File -> New window`. This will cause links to open in another terminal.

Now, my question is how can I change in what terminal does this new links instance opens? On my system, it opens in [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/) but I use [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) so I'd like to make it open in urxvt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [LINKS_XTERM](http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/links-list/2000-August/000473.html) environment variable, e.g.:

```
export LINKS_XTERM="urxvt -e"
```